# Display custom field's value in email template email-order-details.php(overridden template)

Tags: php, email, woocommerce

Just want to show a value which i have taken in custom input, trying to display it in a table when email is sent, also how come this array is printing name,price and quantity only

```
echo $order->email_order_items_table( array(
        'show_sku'      => $sent_to_admin,
        'show_image'    => false,
        'image_size'    => array( 32, 32 ),
        'plain_text'    => $plain_text,
        'sent_to_admin' => $sent_to_admin
    ) );
```

i have tried doing `echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_text_field', true );` but it doesn't display anything maybe i'm missing the key how do i get it ?

Comment: hater could you please tell why are you doing down votes ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_item_meta_end', 'order_custom_field_in_item_meta_end', 10, 4 );
function order_custom_field_in_item_meta_end( $item_id, $item, $order, $plain_text ) {
    $_text_field = get_post_meta( $order->id, '_text_field', true );
    echo '<br/>' . __( 'Your Text Field Label Here' ) . ': ' . $_text_field;
}
```